# Why does the animation keep repeating itself even when not hovering over the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using Javascript & jQuery and I have been trying to make a quick website to show to my music teacher.

When I mouse over an invisible object the animation occasionally starts twice, or repeats forever, then it shows the screen I want it to show.
When I mouse off of it, it just does the normal animation back to 0px, but then for no apparent reason it does the starting animation again, then the off animation, then the start, and so on and so forth.

Here is a snippet of my code. Tell me if you need more.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#song1").hover(function() {
    $(this).css({
      'width': '0px',
      'height': '0px'
    })

    $(this).animate({
      width: '560px',
      height: '315px',
      opacity: '100'
    })
  }, function() {
    $(this).animate({
      width: '0px',
      height: '0px',
      opacity: '0'
    })

    $(this).css({
      'width': '560px',
      'height': '315px'
    })
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey
}

p {
  color: white
}

#song1 {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 560px;
  height: 315px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="song1tx">1.</p>
<div id="song1">
  <p id="song1load" style="color: black">Loading...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: BTW song1 is just a div

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include the HTML. The behaviour you're seeing may be caused by the child elements within the parent div.

Comment: I included what was important if that's alright @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: What are you trying to [accomplish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: I am making a small website to display to my music teacher that has 5 of my favorite songs, she told me to do this because she knows I'm more advanced in computers/technology than most people in my grade. I want a small animation to play when you put your mouse over the div object that displays a youtube embed. I am trying to get this to work before I add the embed.

Comment: I just read the whole thing about the XY problem, yeah, that sucks. Sorry. But I simply want to make an animation to display an embed when you mouse over it.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the element only if it's animating:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#song1:not(:animated)").hover(function() {
        $(this).css({
            'width': '0px',
            'height': '0px'
          });
      
          $(this).animate({
            width: '560px',
            height: '315px',
            opacity: '100'
          });
    });

    $("#song1").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '0px',
            height: '0px',
            opacity: '0'
          })
      
          $(this).css({
            'width': '560px',
            'height': '315px'
          })
    });

});
```

Comment: This stops it from playing at all...

Comment: Just edited, take a look

Comment: Now it shows perfectly fine, but when I make my mouse leave nothing happens

Comment: Try to use the mouseout event (code updated)

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: If you could it would be nice if you could make your own testing files, it's fairly easy to set up.

Comment: @ConnorGilroy A JS Fiddle might help the user help you. https://jsfiddle.net/